# 3 splash in one activity and button is not working

Tags: java, android, android-activity, timer, splash-screen

i have a splash activity that i want to show 3 pictures in slide mode on each 2 seconds, and i want to add skip button into splash screen but its not working.

here is my splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom|right"
android:background="#000000">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slidesplash"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:maxHeight="360dp"
        android:maxWidth="360dp"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="how can i change the background of this button in each 2 seconds?"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splashskip"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/splashskip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my splash.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Splash extends Activity {
Button Button;
// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 6000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    getActionBar().hide();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.splashskip);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

}}
```

here is the picture of splash

[image: splash]

Comment: can you please post the full error stack?

Comment: i am using AIDE the only error its giving is these two line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside splash.java change:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
Button Button;
```

to

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
Button button;
```

Comment: thanks its fixed the error but now when i run the app the button in not doing anything i have to wait until the splash ends

Comment: well, that is beyond the scope of your original question. Please consider marking the answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: my main question is about how to set 3 pictures in a row in one splash activity

Comment: There are several issues with your code and your original intent. I helped you getting your program to run, at least. Edit your question accordingly and I may be able to help you further. Your layouts and Manifest are irrelevant at this point

Comment: i thing the button is not working because the splash time out is not letting the button work until the time is over.

Comment: its 4:20AM in my country so i will back about 8 hours later

Comment: First of all: there are several alternatives to implement a button's changing background. But I'm not sure you need it. I think you are probably better off with an ImageView. Your question is still very vague to me. Sorry.